# Bootable USB stick with Truecrypt

Tags: hard-drive, boot, encryption, truecrypt

I want to boot the TrueCrypt rescue disk from a USB flash drive. I have Windows 7 64bit so I cannot use `Grub4Dos` to do this (it only works on 32bit system), and 99% of all documentations on how to create this rescue USB stick involve `Grub4Dos`.

So I tried using a program called `FlashBoot` but couldn't figure it out. I did some operation on the USB stick using `FlashBoot`, to make the USB bootable or something to a DVD ISO. However as I got lost and wasn't sure what I was doing, i abandoned `FlashBoot` and just formatted the USB stick.

Then I found the following instructions to USE `syslinux` for this purpose:

> mephisto wrote:
>   Ok, this is how it worked for me:
>
> 1. Format the USB-Stick with FAT
> 2. Download the newest SYSLINUX package.
> 3. Extract the `syslinux` archive (in my case the newest one was `syslinux-3.70.zip`)
> 4. The only 2 files you actually need from the archive are `syslinux.exe` from the `win32` directory.... and `memdisk` from the `memdisk` directory.
> 5. Assuming your USB-Stick has the drive letter X, execute the following command: `syslinux X:`
> 6. After that there should be a (hidden) file on your USB-Stick called `ldlinux.sys`
> 7. Download BBIE or (any other image extractor you know works).
> 8. Assuming your USB-Stick das the drive letter X, execute the following command: `bbie TruecryptRescueDisk.iso`. Then this process should have created a file called `image1.bin`
> 9. Rename `image1.bin` to something like `tc.img`
> 10. Copy (the previously extracted file) `memdisk` and `tc.img` to your USB-Stick
> 11. Create a file on the USB-Stick called `syslinux.cfg` with the following content: `default memdisk initrd=tc.img`

I followed those instructions to the letter. Before doing so I again formatted the USB stick, this time as FAT32 with 16k. Then I tried to restart the system. This is what I saw ([large version](http://imagebin.org/159801)):

[image]

Now why on Earth would it say `FlashBoot` loader there? It seems very bizarre. I formatted the USB stick, a full format that took like 5 minutes. Not only that but after seeing this I formatted it like 5 times and redid the above instructions and still see this screen.

Does anyone have an idea where I am going wrong here?

<sub>I'm asking this question here and not on the Truecrypt forums because they really frown upon people asking this question there, as it has been answered many times. They simply will not help. However my case has not been answered by the numerous tutorials on the internet.</sub>

Comment: The bios is definitely capable of booting from usb and i made the usb stick the 1st in the boot order list.

Comment: UPDATE: i used diskpart to DELETE OVERRIDE the usb flash drive, and that gave me a RAW volume which i then formatted. Then I repeated the above steps. That removed any mention of FlashBook, but now when i reboot i just get a sentence about syslinux and about its copyright, creator et al. So something still is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

After spending 4 hours trying to fix the same issue (I accidentally overwrote TrueCrypt's boot loader with grub...) I finally found a way to make this work with grub4dos on my 64bit Asus Eeee PC:

It's roughly the steps described at http://stdout-dev-null.blogspot.fr/2010/02/truecrypt-rescue-disk-on-usb.html except that the grub4dos install procedure that is described there is not working so the way to make this actually work is to use an ISO that already installs grub4dos properly for you such as the ultimate boot cd: http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html

1: Follow the steps to put it on an USB stick: http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/customize.html

2: Add your TrueCrypt recovery .iso image at the root of your drive (name it tc.iso)

3: Edit G:\ubcd\menus\grub4dos\main.lst (where G: is you usb stick) and add the following at the bottom:

```
title TRUECRYPT RESCUE DISK 
find --set-root /tc.iso 
map --mem /tc.iso (hd32) 
map (hd0) (hd1) 
map (hd1) (hd0) 
map --hook 
root (hd32) 
chainloader (hd32)
```

You may need to adapt the `map` part of the config above because the truecrypt recovery will only write to 'drive 0' (I'm not sure if this is particular to my setup)

(by default drive 0 is the device you are booting from - your USB stick)

Then boot from the USB stick, select `grub4dos menu` (at the bottom) then select `TRUECRYPT RESCUE DISK`
The TC boot loader will start asking you for your password, ignore that and use the recovery options.

Note that in my case I had to recover the boot loader AND the volume keys else my password was not recognised. Then Windows 7 x64 happily booted without issue.

Comment: The referenced receipe is working  perfectly on a 64bit Dell.

Comment: I can confirm that this works when MBR within encrypted Windows system partition becomes corrupt. I had no other way of booting from the recovery ISO, and this is the only method listed online that has worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Download [UNETBOOTIN](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and burn the TrueCrypt ISO to a ThumbDrive. I've done this on my current laptop and it works.

Comment: Didn't work for me - CD works fine, not USB

Answer (score 1):

FlashBoot author here.

You've solved it yourself, but we mention how to remove FlashBoot loader from USB thumbdrive in documentation: 
http://www.prime-expert.com/flashboot/user_guide.php
(see section "Reverting Multiformat to Normal").

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the syslinux bootloader. You can use grub2 as an alternative.

But the easiest way to do this, is to create a bootable USB stick with UBCD4win or any other recovery disk. They always have the bootloader included.

Alternatives to UBCD4win are also possible and listed underneath UBCD.

- [UBCD4win Download (not the official one, but that one is dead)](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/ubcd4win.html)
- [HBCD Download](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/)
- Explanation on how to [install HBCD to USB](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd-on-usb-disk).

You can use the explanation on the HBCD to USB page also for your truecrypt ISO.

Comment: The link to UBCD4win is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Coming very late to this table but YUMI is able to create a bootable USB version of the TrueCrypt recovery disk as shown here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/technical/thread/b32f9cb2/

It mentions Veracrypt, the fork of TrueCrypt but the same process works. Note the additional steps needed to swap the hard disks over before password is accepted.